# Dynamically adding annotations are not rendering in iOS

Tags: ios, swiftui, dynamic, annotations, mapbox

Strange that the Mapbox SDK for ios makes the updating of annotations at runtime straight-forward, but the new annotations aren't rendering for me when running in xcode. **Any thoughts what the issue could be?**

The expectation is for each new point to be added every 5s second until the timer is canceled.

```
// ViewModel - Periodically add annotation via timer

class MapViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var coords: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = [];
    
    var _coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = [];
    var _index: Int = 0
    
    init() {
        
        _coordinates.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.730610, longitude: 73.935242))
        _coordinates.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.0534, longitude: 73.5387))
        _coordinates.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.3082, longitude: 72.9250))
        _coordinates.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.7658, longitude: 72.6734))
        _coordinates.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.2626, longitude: 71.8023))
        _coordinates.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.3601, longitude: 71.0589))
        
        self.startTimer()
    }
    
    func startTimer() {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5.0, repeats: true) { timer in
            print("latitude: \(self._coordinates[self._index].latitude), longitude: \(self._coordinates[self._index].longitude)")
            
            self.coords.append(self._coordinates[self._index])
            self._index += 1
            
            print(self._index)
            
            if (self._index > 5) {
                print("Timer Canceled")
                timer.invalidate()
            } else {
                print ("Time Continuing")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
// Update View Callback
import SwiftUI
import MapboxMaps

struct MapBoxMapView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: MapViewModel
     
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MapViewController {
           return MapViewController()
       }
      
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MapViewController, context: Context) {
        if let lastElement = viewModel.coords.last {
            // Use the last element
            print("The last element is: \(lastElement)")
            let pm = uiViewController.mapView.annotations.makePointAnnotationManager()
            
            var point = PointAnnotation(coordinate: lastElement)
            
            // Make the annotation show a red pin
            point.image = .init(image: UIImage(named: "red_pin")!, name: "red_pin")
            point.iconAnchor = .bottom

            // Add the annotation to the manager in order to render it on the map.
            pm.annotations = [point]
        } else {
            // The array is empty
            print("The array is empty.")
        }
    }
}
```

......